# image in facebook for an object

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook

So I have an image taken from the API, which has the following format:

```
http://mytestapi.com/api/cat/cat_image?cat_item_primary_key=51235470&image_type=icon&width=60&height=60.jpg
```

However, when I give this image to facebook as the image property it doesn't work. However if I give out some random image I found on the web it shows the image on open graph. Why is this?
Does facebook have certain restrictions on images?

Comment: Do you just send the url to facebook? Or do you send image data?

Comment: I sent the URL to facebook and it seems that this image can't be uploaded to imgur as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sending the proper content type with that image? Seems unlikely if it's being rejected from two services.

Try `curl -I http://mytestapi.com/api/cat/cat_image?cat_item_primary_key=51235470&image_type=icon&width=60&height=60.jpg` to show the headers you're sending and see if the content type is correct for your image.